# how to change hsv tensor into rgb tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to an op which can convert HSV tensor (shape:`[batch_size, image_width, image_height, num_channels]`,channels means `h, s, v`) into RGB tensor(`[batch_size, image_width, image_height,num_channels]`, channels means r, g, b]). And I know the existed `tf.image.hsv_to_rgb`, while it seems to an image preprocessing function and cannot get gradient. For creating the conversation op, whether we need write codes from scratch using some meta-ops (eg. `tf.multiply()`, `tf.add()`,etc.)

```
new_image_hsv = tf.random_normal(shape=[32,32,3]) 
new_image_rgb = tf.image.hsv_to_rgb(new_image_hsv, name='hsv2rgb') 
hsv2rgb = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('hsv2rgb') 
print('hsv2rgb: ', get_gradient_function(hsv2rgb)) #hsv2rgb: None
```

Comment: What's the point of having a gradient in a operation like a conversion ? Could you please add details ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the HSV to RGB conversion function has no registered gradient, you could consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) about it. However, looking at the [implementation of the kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.10.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/adjust_saturation_op.cc), it is entirely possible to replicate the computation using basic TensorFlow operations with defined gradients:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_hsv_to_rgb(tensor):
    h = tensor[..., 0]
    s = tensor[..., 1]
    v = tensor[..., 2]
    c = s * v;
    m = v - c;
    dh = h * 6
    h_category = tf.cast(dh, tf.int32)
    fmodu = tf.mod(dh, 2)
    x = c * (1 - tf.abs(fmodu - 1))
    component_shape = tf.shape(tensor)[:-1]
    dtype = tensor.dtype
    rr = tf.zeros(component_shape, dtype=dtype)
    gg = tf.zeros(component_shape, dtype=dtype)
    bb = tf.zeros(component_shape, dtype=dtype)
    h0 = tf.equal(h_category, 0)
    rr = tf.where(h0, c, rr)
    gg = tf.where(h0, x, gg)
    h1 = tf.equal(h_category, 1)
    rr = tf.where(h1, x, rr)
    gg = tf.where(h1, c, gg)
    h2 = tf.equal(h_category, 2)
    gg = tf.where(h2, c, gg)
    bb = tf.where(h2, x, bb)
    h3 = tf.equal(h_category, 3)
    gg = tf.where(h3, x, gg)
    bb = tf.where(h3, c, bb)
    h4 = tf.equal(h_category, 4)
    rr = tf.where(h4, x, rr)
    bb = tf.where(h4, c, bb)
    h5 = tf.equal(h_category, 5)
    rr = tf.where(h5, c, rr)
    bb = tf.where(h5, x, bb)
    r = rr + m
    g = gg + m
    b = bb + m
    return tf.stack([r, g, b], axis=-1)
```

Testing it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, 3))
# Compute builtin conversion to check that our conversion is correct
tf_conversion = tf.image.hsv_to_rgb(img)
my_conversion = my_hsv_to_rgb(img)
# Difference between the builtin conversion and ours
error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(tf_conversion, my_conversion)
# Take gradients of the conversion
my_conversion_grad = tf.gradients(my_conversion, img)[0]
# Test it
with tf.Session() as sess:
    np.random.seed(100)
    random_img = np.random.rand(10, 10, 3)
    error_val, grad_val = sess.run([error, my_conversion_grad],
                                    feed_dict={img: random_img})
    print(error_val)
    print(grad_val)
```

Output:

```
Error:
1.914486e-16
Gradient:
[[[-7.0903623e-01 -5.3507453e-01  2.6491349e+00]
  [-3.4420034e-03 -1.2991568e-01  2.9949572e+00]
  [ 6.7739707e-01 -2.7006465e-01  1.3685231e+00]
  [-1.1187987e+00 -3.0346024e-01  1.7070839e+00]
  [-1.4286079e-01 -2.4429685e-01  2.8794882e+00]
  [-8.3736974e-01 -3.2182935e-01  1.4807379e+00]
  [ 7.0991272e-01 -4.7601932e-01  2.6977921e+00]
  [-1.6489303e+00 -5.5128366e-01  1.6589090e+00]
  [-1.2725148e-02 -5.9869420e-03  2.6076081e+00]
  [-7.2826855e-02 -2.3104541e-02  1.7949229e+00]]
#...
```

However, note that the HSV to RGB conversion is not a continuous function ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV)), which is possibly the reason why it does not have defined gradient. This means that the gradients may not always indicate a proper optimization direction, due to this "jumps" in the definition of the conversion.